# Icon does not appear when I use iconbitmap()

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

OS: Linux - Ubantu

Image I have used: It was originally .ico but I converted online to .xbm

I tried different images and different websites but nothing seems to work

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

root.title("B")
root.iconbitmap('@/home/zaki/Pictures/mar.xbm')


root.mainloop()
```

The window appears normally but without icon

Comment: Use an ico instead of xbm? or go [here](https://convertio.co/ico-xbm/)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the `iconphoto()` method.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

img = PhotoImage(file="image.png")  # Replace "image.png" with any image file.
root.iconphoto(False, img)

root.mainloop()
```

Works on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.6.

**References:**
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iconphoto-method-in-tkinter-python/